# Javascript to modify style elements on mobile devices for responsive (collapse collodion)

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to load all my collodion open on desktop and tablet, closed on small mobile devices and also remove some icons.

I'm using Wordpress, so I tryed to write a javascript myself. I never was good on javascript, and now I'm also a bit rugged.

This is my not-working code, put between  and ...  in my page:

```
<script>
$(window).bind('resize load', function() {
if ($(this).width() < 767) {
var ico document.getElementById("loc");
for (g=0;i<ico.lenght;g++) {
ico[g].style["display"] = 'none';
}
var collaps = document.getElementsByClassName('collapseomatic_content');
for(i=0; i<collaps.length; i++) {
collaps[i].style["display"] = 'none');
}
}
}
</script>
```

I want to change to "none" the display proprietes inside style for all all the accordion witch uses the class "collapsematic_content" and add "display:none" to all images with "loc" ID and... but it isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: first and most important, NEVER use same Id to different elements, Id MUST be unique, so `"all images with 'Ioc' ID"` won't work, change it to class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have some syntax errors, I fixed then and I made an snippet example below. (I commented the `if statement` just to be able to show the code working, adjust it as you need).

```js
$(window).bind('resize load', function() {
  //if ($(this).width() < 767) {
    var ico = document.getElementsByClassName("loc");
    for (g=0; g < ico.length; g++) {    
      ico[g].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var collaps = document.getElementsByClassName('collapseomatic_content');
    for(i=0; i < collaps.length; i++) {
      collaps[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  //}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="loc" alt="imageA"/>
<img class="NOTloc" alt="imageB"/>
<img class="loc" alt="imageC"/>

<div class="collapseomatic_content">A</div>
<div class="NOTcollapseomatic_content">B</div>
<div class="collapseomatic_content">C</div>
```

Also, take a look at CSS [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), it can help you in some cases that you just wnat to change the CSS attributes based on screen size.